# Вместо приложения открывается директория

Tags: php, iis

я пытаюсь запустить приложение на php с использованием IIS по данной инструкции https://gistoolkit.ru/download/prezents/giswebserverseinstall.pdf
Вместо этого [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я получаю это [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как мне решить данную проблему? делал все по инструкции.

Comment: Может забыли добавить http:// вначале?

Comment: @dresqd, нет, это я точно не забыл)

Comment: Может не указано, что htp-файлы, а конкретно index.php может служить в качестве индексного файла на сервере и в этой папке? Ищет index.html, не находит его и вываливает вам содержимое папки, вместо запуска приложения? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192049/how-to-make-apache-serve-index-php-instead-of-index-html

Comment: @Quazimorda, попробовал добавить в файл .htaccess DirectoryIndex index.php, не помогло

Comment: Я не помню точно где... в настройках самого iis есть индексные файлы, надо добавить index.php в этот список

Comment: @SwaD, спасибо, действительно это так. Нужно было в настройках IIS добавить index.php во вкладке "Документ по умолчанию"